# How to explain this issue with variable scope?

Tags: javascript, scope

Why does the second function output an empty array?

```
var global = ["abc"];

function test1() {
    var g = global || [];
    console.log(g);             //outputs: ["abc"]
}

function test2() {
    var global = global || [];
    console.log(global);        //outputs: []
}
```

Comment: You probably shouldn't be purposefully shadowing variables like this to begin with.

Comment: Note that `var`s get hoisted, so it's actually `var global; global = global || []` - where `global` is hence `undefined`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While it seems like it should work because assignment works right to left, you need to consider that ***variable declarations are hoisted***.

To the interpreter, your code actually looks like this:

```
function test2() {
    var global; // global is undefined

    global = global || []; // because undefined is falsey, the [] is assigned

    console.log(global); // displays the []
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`var global` redefines the symbol `global` to be a local variable within the scope of that function, thus making the other `global` invisible.  If you want to do what that second function does, use a different name:

```
var global = ["abc"];

function test2() {
    var local = global || [];
    console.log(local);        //outputs: ["abc"]
}
```

or, if the original definition of `global` is truly a global variable, you can use the window object to reference it, when it's regular symbol is hidden by a local variable (though I would not suggest doing this because it will likely confuse people trying to understand your code):

```
var global = ["abc"];

function test2() {
    var global = window.global || [];
    console.log(global);        //outputs: ["abc"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it outputs an empty name is because once you have conflicting names.  There is both a local and global named `global`.  Inside the function which defines `global` as a local all occurrences will refer to the local.  It will never see the global value.

Hence the line `var global = global || []` interprets `global` as a local.  It is currently `undefined` hence it chooses `[]`.

One way to make this work is to use the qualified name for the global instance

```
function test2() {
  var global = window.global || [];
  console.log(global); // outputs ["abc"]
}
```